# context hook cant store value

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Code below works fine except when call `Add` function which adds new number to array,
array contains only last added item.

dont understand why it does not store IDs

App.ts

```
import MyComponent from "./main";
import { FavoriteContext, usePostsContextValue } from "./store";

function App() {
  const postsContextValue = usePostsContextValue();
  return (
    <FavoriteContext.Provider value={postsContextValue}>
        <MyComponent />
      </Container>
    </FavoriteContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Component:

```
import { FavoriteContext } from "../store";
...

function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<certificates[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);
  const { IDs, Add, Remove } = useContext(FavoriteContext);



  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("IDs", IDs); //logs only 1 item, last selected Id
  }, [IDs]);

  const handleAddClick= async (id: number) => {
    Add(id);
  };


  const columns: TableColumn<certificates>[] = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      {
        name: "STATUS",
        cell: (row) => <strong>{status(row.status)}</strong>,
      },
      {
        cell: (row) => {
          return (
            <IconButton onClick={() => handleAddClick(row.id)}>
              <BookmarkBorderIcon />
            </IconButton>
          );
        },
        button: true,
      },
    ];
  }, []);

  return (
    <DataTable
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      pagination
      paginationServer
      paginationTotalRows={totalRows}
      onChangeRowsPerPage={handlePerRowsChange}
      onChangePage={handlePageChange}
    />
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Context.ts:

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { favouriteType } from "../models";

export const defaultValue: favouriteType = {
  IDs: [],
  Add: (id: number) => {},
  Remove: (id: number) => {},
};
export const FavoriteContext = React.createContext<favouriteType>(defaultValue);

function usePostsContextValue(): favouriteType {
  const [IDs, setIDs] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const Add = (id: number) => {
    setIDs([...IDs, id]);
  };

  const Remove = (id: number) => {
    const newPosts = [...IDs];
    const removedPostIndex = newPosts.findIndex((f) => f === id);
    if (removedPostIndex > -1) {
      newPosts.splice(removedPostIndex, 1);
    }
    setIDs(newPosts);
  };

  return {
    IDs,
    Add,
    Remove,
  };
}

export { usePostsContextValue };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time, a new ID is added, a new `Add` function is created which would capture the value of the new ID.

```js
  const Add = (id: number) => {
    setIDs([...IDs, id]); // <-- this capture the ID of the outer scope
  };
```

This works as expected, however looking at the component below:

```
  const columns: TableColumn<certificates>[] = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      {
        name: "STATUS",
        cell: (row) => <strong>{status(row.status)}</strong>,
      },
      {
        cell: (row) => {
          return (
            <IconButton onClick={() => handleAddClick(row.id)}>
              <BookmarkBorderIcon />
            </IconButton>
          );
        },
        button: true,
      },
    ];
  }, []);
```

Since this component is never rerendered, the `Add` function is not updated, so it is always the first version where the captured `IDs` is empty `[]`. Thus adding one ID is always:

```
const Add = (id: number) => {
    setIDs([...[], id]); // the first vesion of Add captured IDs = [];
  };
```

and always have only the last ID.

The solution is to include `handleAddClick` (which captures the new `Add` function in the useMemo dep array:

```js
  const columns: TableColumn<certificates>[] = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      {
        name: "STATUS",
        cell: (row) => <strong>{status(row.status)}</strong>,
      },
      {
        cell: (row) => {
          return (
            <IconButton onClick={() => handleAddClick(row.id)}>
              <BookmarkBorderIcon />
            </IconButton>
          );
        },
        button: true,
      },
    ];
  }, [handleAddClick]);
```

However, this destroys the purpose of `useMemo` since `Add`/`handleAddClick` always recreated on every render, so the solution is to wrap both of them in `useCallback`.

```js
  const Add = useCallback((id: number) => {
    setIDs([...IDs, id]);
  }, [IDs]); // notice I have to include IDs here so that the function can be recreated with the new IDs.

  const handleAddClick= useCallback(async (id: number) => {
    Add(id);
  }, []);
```

Better yet, you can use the function syntax of `setState`, which removes the need to include `IDs` in the dep array, improving performance.

```js
  const Add = useCallback((id: number) => {
    setIDs((prevIDs) => [...prevIDs, id]); // the function form will receive the previous state as the argument.
  }, []);
```